# Can I install Windows 8 and Windows xp sp2 in single pc?

Tags: operating-systems, multi-boot

I want to install Windows 8 and Windows xp sp2 in single PC. Is this Possible. DualOperating Systems in single pc.

Comment: If you are going to dual boot Windows XP and Windows 8 at least have the decency to install ALL security patches for Windows XP.  There is a list a mile long of security vulerabilities for Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just install the older one (XP) first. And then install Windows 8 on another partition of HDD. Even if the bootloader doesn't show you an option to select the WinXP at boot you can use **BCDEdit** utility to modify your boot options in Windows 8 later on and get a nice menu with the choices.